# Manga where the main character wakes up after 100-200 years of sleep in a cryopod

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character is a hero and he wakes up after 100 or maybe 200 years of sleep in a cryopod thing. He wakes up in a kid's body, then he meets an elf he rescued before he got into the cryopod.

Comment: Immidiately thought of *Breath of the Wild*, though it's not a manga..

Comment: It sounds like a garbled version of "*The Reincarnation Magician Of The Inferior Eyes*"

Comment: @Random_person - I see that an anonymous user submitted an edit to your question. If that person is you, I gather you must no longer have access to your previous account. In order to regain access to that account -- and with it, the ability to edit this question yourself -- please follow the instructions provided at [this link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: For the records, asker created a duplicate unregistered account to confirm that Valorum's suggestion, _The Reincarnation Magician Of The Inferior Eyes_, is the right one (with a "thank you" answer which was deleted), if someone wants to write an actual answer.